# Best method to use to make a script run for a certain amount of time?

Tags: php, cron

I have a script that I want to run continuously for about an hour and a half between a certain time period; obviously running it in the browser isn't the most ideal way, so wondering what is the best method? Would running it via a cronjob be the best way to go?

I guess the way to run it for a certain amount of time would just to set `set_time_limit()` to the amount of time you want it to run for or is there a better way?

Comment: launch by cron yes, keep running is a little unclear, what's the script doing? set_time_limit is infinite if called from the command line (cli) so that's not an issue. some hosts wont allow this - so that could be an issue

Comment: @dagon It's basically continually checking the status of something during a certain time period. I meant to add a value in the `set_time_limit()` function, such as `set_time_limit(3600)`; which should allow it to run for an hour correct?

Comment: put in i never ending while loop and maybe do a time check as well as set_time_limit() << that returns a fatal error which is a little ugly vs a time check and graceful exit

Comment: @dagon well no-one will be seeing the output as it's being run via cron so an ugly error shouldn't matter right!? :)

Comment: what about the system error logs? your call.

Comment: @dagon True; something to keep in mind :)